# How can I change my pygame paddle to move from mouse positioning from keys

Tags: python, pygame

```
def move(self):
    #reset movement direction
    self.path = 0
    key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if key[pygame.K_LEFT] and self.rect.left > 0:
        self.rect.x -= self.speed
        self.path = -1
    if key[pygame.K_RIGHT] and self.rect.right < screenw:
        self.rect.x += self.speed
        self.path = 1
```

I am getting it to work with the keys but am stuck on how to change it to mouse positioning

Answer (score 1):

Just set the `centery` attribute of the paddle by the x coordinate of the mouse cursor. The position of the mouse cane be get with [`pygame.mouse.get_pos`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mouse.html). [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) provides a lot of virtual attributes, which can be used to get and set the location and size of the rectangle.

```py
mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
self.rect.centery = mouse_pos[1]
```

If you want the paddle to move slowly in the direction of the mouse, you need to calculate the distance from the center of the paddle to the mouse:

```py
mouse_buttons = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
if any(mouse_buttons)
    mouse_x, mouse_y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    dy = mouse_y - self.rect.centery
    if dy < 0:
        self.rect.y -= min(-dy, self.speed)
        self.path = -1
    elif dy > 0:
        self.rect.y += min(dy, self.speed)
        self.path = 1
```